# iOS: Play FLV stream

Tags: ios, streaming

I have FLV streaming URL, I need to play it in iOS. I might need to use ffmpeg to convert it into mp4 stream, how would I do that for the streams?
Any sample url from ffmpeg site etc.?

Thanks
Ayaz Alavi

Comment: I remember being able to play FLV videos using Adobe Flex.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/VideoDisplay.html
 However I don't know if it also works for streams.

Comment: I am looking for objective-c solution

Comment: The I guess you will have to use ffmpeg :(